# How can I change the color of the parenthesis syntax for a .py script in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been struggling with this for 2 days.

Basically, when you edit the user settings .json file, it will override any theme colors.

I totally installed a brand new fresh Visual Studio Code for Mac, and it has zero extensions, zero account, zero syncing.

So, I tried adding the following to the user settings .json file, to no avail:

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      }
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "punctuation.definition.arguments.begin.python",
          "punctuation.definition.arguments.end.python",
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#00FF00"  // Neon green, baby!
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, it seems to be picking up the green rule change:

[rule change but no change green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rdyu.png)

Yet, no change occurs, even after restart:

[nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2DQc.png)

So, how can I do it? How can I change those pesky parenthesis colors? The theme I'm using is the default "Solarized Dark", which seems to be able to change the parenthesis in a python script, as in `print()`, to the color white, just fine!

Comment: what exactly do you want to change the colour of? the "`(`" and "`)`"? The stuff inside them (the function arguments?)

Comment: The actual parenthesis character, IE: "(" and ")".

Comment: this is... weird. any different if you disable your Python extension and then reload VS Code? Or what if you disable semantic highlighting?